# Is it possible to sum all of the duplicated in a column from a table in sql?

Tags: sql

I have a column called sqrft and I want to be able to sum all the data that has a pair if that makes sense. Below is the column data in sqrft:

```
1030, 1575, 1167, 1574, 1030, 745, 1680, 1084, 1084
```

I've only been able to find material on how to display only non duplicates so I'm a bit stuck on how to do it this way. Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: Are you really storing comma separated values in a single column?

Comment: "sum all the data that has a pair if that makes sense".  No, that does not make sense.  What is a "pair"?  Are the values in a string or in separate rows.  Clarify your quesiton.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the group by and having clause to find duplicates.

```
select value 
from (
  select count(1), value 
  from test
  group by value
  having count(1) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT 
       sqrft,
       SUM(sqrft) AS sum,
       COUNT(*) 
   FROM table 
   GROUP BY sqrft 
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Here is a SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09b440/1/0